# Can I require/import files for a ViewModel in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, laravel, mvvm, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js for an MVVM project and I want to separate out the View and ViewModel as much as possible for code maintainability and testing.
Here is my Example.vue file:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Example: {{message}}</h1>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
require('../ViewModels/Example');
export default {
    data() {
        return new Example();
    }
}
</script>
```

Then here is the Example.js file:

```
class Example {
    constructor() {
        this.message = "Hello World";
    }
}
```

But I get an Error: "ReferenceError: Example is not defined"
If I paste the Example class into my script tag it works fine but when I try importing or requiring it doesn't work.
Anyone have an idea why?

Comment: you either need to export the class or you need to explicitly declare it, i.e. `var Example = require('../ViewModels/Example')`

Comment: If I do that I get the error: "Example is not a constructor."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
I needed to import and export in a specific way so my Example.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Example: {{message}}</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Example from '../ViewModels/Example';

    export default {
        data() {
            return new Example();
        }
    }
</script>
```

and my Example.js class file:

```
export default class Example {
    constructor() {
        this.message = "Hello World";
    }
}
```